# Selenium Webdriver - verify text box write-protected?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can we verify whether a field is write-protected (that is, readonly) in Selenium using Java code?

Best regards

Comment: is there an attribute in html that shows that the box is protected?

Comment: yea- there is a field called 'readonly'. following details are specific to this field----


<input id="username" class="textbox-signup" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" tabindex="2" name="userName">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to write something via sendkeys() and check that value attribute of textbox has not been changed.

Comment: Thanks for all these replies. somehow i experimented all these ideas and i implemented the chosen one. 
    WebElement usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    usernameElement.sendKeys("SampleText");

Answer (score 17):

1. **isEnabled()** does not have any common things to readonly.
2. **String attribute  = element.getAttribute("readonly");** will not fail your test even "readonly" is absent. In this case it returns ***null***, but we need exception.

Use like this:

```
    WebElement some_element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));
    String readonly = some_element.getAttribute("readonly");
    Assert.assertNotNull(readonly);
```

Do NOT verify **getAttribute("readonly").equals("true")** or similar, in different browsers it can be different as well. (readonly="readonly" in IE, readonly="" in FF, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The `WebElement` interface has a function called [isEnabled](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/#is-enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know for what you need that check i'll post some examples that might be usefull.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:not([readonly='readonly'])[type='text']"));
```

=> returns all text input fields that are editable

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("username");
//can fail if the attribute is not there
String attribute  = element.getAttribute("readonly");
```

=> might need a try catch block

Comment: how to write for selenium RC?

Comment: can't help you with that I am only using webdriver and grid2

Comment: @Tarken: After getting attribute of element, it needs verification. How can it be done?

Comment: Hi u still need an answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

with selenium-java 2.21.0 you can check if its enabled

```
driver.findElement(By.id("...")).isEnabled()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but because I'm working on this recently, I'd like to share my solution.

I implemented a method to test if a text box is read-only or not. I'm working on a Django project so the code is in Python, but I believe it's easy to port it to Java:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase

class MyTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def _is_text_box_read_only(self, web_element):
        old_text = web_element.get_attribute("value")
        web_element.send_keys("test")
        new_text = web_element.get_attribute("value")
        web_element.clear()
        web_element.send_keys(old_text)  # Resume to the previous text
        return old_text == new_text
```

Note that:

1. You need to use the attribute `value` to get the entered text.
2. Better to resume to the previous text after the testing.
3. The code is just an excerpt that shows the core ideas. It may not be runnable.

Comment: You might want to set the old text back in case the field is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Code works best for me. Hope this will be usefull

```
    WebElement fieldName = driver.findElement(By.id("enter_id"));
    fieldName.sendKeys("abc");
    String fieldNameVal = fieldName.getAttribute("value");
    if(fieldNameVal.contentEquals("abc")){
    System.out.println("Field is editable");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Field is non editable" + fieldNameVal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been answered.  but unfortunately, when I facing a similar issue, I had to spend some time to find the correct solution.
I agree that .getAttribute("readonly") returns null but to handle it >
I wrote something similar to this:

```
public boolean isreadOnly(element) {        
    Boolean readOnly = false;       
    readOnly = ((element.getAttribute("disabled") != null) || (element.getAttribute("readonly") != null));  
    return readOnly;        
}
```

and call above:

```
WebElement text = driver.findElement("locator"));  
return isReadOnly(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another answer, using javascript

```
Boolean isEditable = js.executeScript("if(arguments[0].nodeName==='INPUT' || arguments[0].nodeName==='TEXTAREA'){ return !arguments[0].disabled && !arguments[0].readOnly; }else{ return arguments[0].isContentEditable};", webelement);
```

This answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269518 and is simplified a bit.
In regular Javascript, it would look like this:

```
function isEditable(element){
    if(element.nodeName==="INPUT" || element.nodeName==="TEXTAREA"){
        return !element.disabled && !element.readOnly;
    }else{
        return element.isContentEditable;
    }
}
```

This addresses both the "readOnly" and the "disabled" properties, and it can be used on any type of element.