# How to check if the selected text is editable?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Chrome extension that deals with text selection. I want to detect whether the selected text is editable. Given a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object returned by [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection), is it possible to check whether the selected text is editable? How?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information here.

Comment: You can't check if text is editable using the selection, you need to check the container control.

Comment: A selection can contain text from multiple elements. Some elements may be editable and some may not.

Comment: @w3bMak3r yeah sure! Like what?

Comment: @Oriol what if we say the element at which the selection starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A selection can contain text from multiple elements. Some elements may be editable and some may not.

However, if you are only interested in the element where the selection starts, you can use

- [`Selection.prototype.anchorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.anchorNode), which returns the `Node` in which the selection begins.
- [`Node.prototype.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode), which should be the `Element` in which the selection begins. Latest browsers also support [`Node.prototype.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement).
- [`HTMLElement.prototype.isContentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.isContentEditable), a read-only property returns a Boolean that is `true` if the contents of the element are editable; otherwise it returns `false`.

That is:

```js
getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.isContentEditable
```

However, that won't work for `input` and `textarea` elements because:

- `getSelection()` won't return selections in them, because their value doesn't exist as a text node. You can use [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) instead.
- `isContentEditable` won't apply because you edit their value instead of their content. Instead, you should check if they are `disabled` or `readOnly` (`disabled` ones doesn't seem to be selectable, but you can check just in case).

```js
function isEditable() {
    var el = document.activeElement; // focused element
    if(el && ~['input','textarea'].indexOf(el.tagName.toLowerCase())
        return !el.readOnly && !el.disabled;
    el = getSelection().anchorNode; // selected node
    if(!el) return undefined; // no selected node
    el = el.parentNode; // selected element
    return el.isContentEditable;
}
```

```js
var el;
function isEditable() {
  if(el) el.className = '';
  el = document.activeElement; // focused element
  if(el && ~['input','textarea'].indexOf(el.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
    el.className = 'selected';
    return !el.readOnly && !el.disabled;
  }
  el = getSelection().anchorNode; // selected node
  if(!el) return undefined; // no selected node
  el = el.parentNode; // selected element
  el.className = 'selected';
  return el.isContentEditable;
}

var res = document.getElementById('result');
setInterval(function() {
  res.textContent = isEditable();
}, 200);
```

```css
#result {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.selected {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>Non-editable div</div>
<div contentEditable="true">Editable div</div>
<input value="Editable input" />
<input value="Read-only input" readonly />
<input value="Disabled input" disabled />
<textarea>Editable textarea</textarea>
<textarea readonly>Read-only textarea</textarea>
<textarea disabled>Disabled textarea</textarea>

<hr />

<p>Is editable: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: I think you might have to do a check to see if the input.type is "text". Otherwise it takes checkboxes and other types into account.

Answer (score 0):

Input tags have the attribute `readonly` to tell if the input can be edited.

You can try:

```
if(yourInput.readonly == true) { // where yourInput is the input tag
    // can not be edited
} else {
    // can be edited
}
```

You can tinker with this to fit what you are using.